# Notepad++ Regex Search & Replace White Space Up to A Limit

Tags: regex, notepad++

How do I write a regex in Notepad++ to search and replace all whitespaces (up to a certain point) with a comma?

Original Text

```
468620438 [2012-07-07 00:00:00,307] [Thread-20] INFO  BIZ,Handler,getJobs():Retrieving messages from A...
468620438 [2012-07-07 00:00:00,307] [Thread-20] INFO  BIZ,InterfaceAdaptor,getMessages : Retrieving messages from B
468620453 [2012-07-07 00:00:00,322] [Thread-20] INFO  BIZ,Handler,_getNextMessage():Retrieving messages from B
```

Amended Text

```
468620438,[2012-07-07 00:00:00,307],[Thread-20],INFO,BIZ,Handler,getJobs():Retrieving messages from A...
468620438,[2012-07-07 00:00:00,307],[Thread-20],INFO,BIZ,InterfaceAdaptor,getMessages : Retrieving messages from B
468620453,[2012-07-07 00:00:00,322],[Thread-20],INFO,BIZ,Handler,_getNextMessage():Retrieving messages from B
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to spell out exactly what you want replaced:

Replace

```
^(\S+)\s+(\S+\s+\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+
```

by

```
\1,\2,\3,\4
```

This is easiest because you're complicating things by needing to include knowledge how the fields look like, e.g. the second column includes a space that should *not* be replaced.